# Transit Visa in Cuba

Tags: visas, filipino-citizens, cuba, haiti

I am a Filipino citizen travelling to Haiti but I have to pass through Cuba. My layover to Cuba is more than 12 hours. Do I need to secure a visa prior to my travel?

Answer (score 1):

[Timatic](https://cms.olympicair.com/timatic/webdocsI/spdbmainv.html) is a database used by airlines to determine what documents are required at transit points and destinations. Airlines will refer to Timatic when you check in for your first flight, to make sure you'll be allowed entry at transit point(s) and destination, because the airline will have to fly you back if entry is refused.

Entering your citizenship, transit point, and destination into the Timatic page linked above generates this information about your transit point in Cuba:

*TWOV (Transit Without Visa):*

*Visa required, except for Passengers with a confirmed onward
ticket for a flight to a third country within 72 hours. They
must have documents required for the next destination.*

Thus, if you have a confirmed ticket to and a visa for entry into Haiti, your stay in Cuba of less than 72 hours qualifies you for transiting Cuba without a visa.